# jupyterhub notebook wont open file

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

Im using jupyterhub notebook on a Mac to open a file using R. Whenever I run the script, I get an error that "No such file or directory".

```
data <- read.csv("/Users/max/Downloads/metrics.csv")
```

> Warning message in file(file, "rt"):
> “cannot open file '/Users/max/Downloads/metrics.csv': No such file or directory”
> Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection
> Traceback:

> 1. read.csv("/Users/max/Downloads/Star1.csv")
> 2. read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,
>    .     dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
> 3. file(file, "rt")*

I have tried getting the data path using option key, then path, but I still get the same error.

Any solution please?